# Zf2 change layout depending on loaded modules

Tags: module, zend-framework2

I am searching the internet for over a week now, but I am not able to find anything on this...

So I thought I have to ask a quick question here:

```
  Is it possible to modify the layout depending on loaded modules in zf2? 
  I mean, I have 3 modules: 1. blog 2. admin 3.ads. 
  If i disable the blog from the application.config.php, 
 is it possible for the menu part containing the blog pages to dissapear?
```

example :

menu before disabling:

```
 | Blog | Admin | Ads
```

menu after disabling blog:

```
 | Admin | Ads
```

Is this possible? Thanks for your input!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easily possible since all that the layout does is to render a given navigation. Your Modules should only hook in to the same navigation configuration and add their entries from their own `module.config.php`. If the module is disabled, the configuration won't be there and so it won't be rendered at all.

Comment: I manually render the layout ( e.g. <ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="<?=$this->url('routename', array())?>">name</a></li>
                                    </ul>). I tried using zend 2 navigation, but its not working, with error: Invalid argument: $route must be a non-empty string or null'

Comment: P.s. Its a pleasure to get an answer from you, Sam, saw you all around the site:) Thanks! I am learning zf2 now, so I am not too good at it..

Comment: I suggest learning about [`SpiffyNavigation`](https://github.com/spiffyjr/spiffy-navigation)